# Calculate the policy max percentage

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to get the policy max percentage on my website using `React` but I get a lot of errors.

```
react-dom.production.min.js:5309 Error: Minified React error #301; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=301 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at ta (react-dom.production.min.js:3855:1)
    at zu (react-dom.production.min.js:6955:1)
    at Oc (react-dom.production.min.js:6411:1)
    at bc (react-dom.production.min.js:6400:1)
    at yc (react-dom.production.min.js:6382:1)
    at lc (react-dom.production.min.js:6103:4)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:2898:1
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:289:1)
    at Uo (react-dom.production.min.js:2868:1)
    at Wo (react-dom.production.min.js:2893:1)
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
ou @ react-dom.production.min.js:5309
n.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:5329
si @ react-dom.production.min.js:3182
fu @ react-dom.production.min.js:5463
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:6687
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:289
Uo @ react-dom.production.min.js:2868
Sc @ react-dom.production.min.js:6470
lc @ react-dom.production.min.js:6109
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:2898
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:289
Uo @ react-dom.production.min.js:2868
Wo @ react-dom.production.min.js:2893
Vo @ react-dom.production.min.js:2883
fc @ react-dom.production.min.js:6134
notify @ Subscription.js:23
t.notifyNestedSubs @ Subscription.js:63
t.handleChangeWrapper @ Subscription.js:68
g @ redux.js:220
(anonymous) @ index.js:11
dispatch @ redux.js:638
(anonymous) @ insuranceReducer.ts:146
l @ runtime.js:64
(anonymous) @ runtime.js:281
(anonymous) @ runtime.js:117
r @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
u @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
Show 1 more frame
Show less
react-dom.production.min.js:3855 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #301; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=301 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at ta (react-dom.production.min.js:3855:1)
    at zu (react-dom.production.min.js:6955:1)
    at Oc (react-dom.production.min.js:6411:1)
    at bc (react-dom.production.min.js:6400:1)
    at yc (react-dom.production.min.js:6382:1)
    at lc (react-dom.production.min.js:6103:4)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:2898:1
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:289:1)
    at Uo (react-dom.production.min.js:2868:1)
    at Wo (react-dom.production.min.js:2893:1)
```

I tried to set it using `useState` and get the maximum value using `Math.max(...maxPercentage)`.

```
const [maxPercentage, setMaxPercentage] = useState([] as any);
data.map((d) => setMaxPercentage(getDiscountPercentage(d.amount,d.discountedAmount).toFixed(0)))

<div>Discount {Math.max(...maxPercentage)}%</div>
```

**Code:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ICompanyInsurance } from "../../typings/IDataOffers";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getSelectedAmountItem, getDiscountPercentage, getCashBack } from "../../redux-data/insurance/insuranceSelector";
import { setIdPolicy } from "../../redux-data/insurance/insuranceReducer";
import { companyImage, companyImages } from "../../constants/companyImages";

//import im from '../../assets/img/providna.webp';

interface IPolicy extends ICompanyInsurance {
  formId?: string;
  index?: number;
  onBuy?: Function;
  onPay?: Function;
}

const Policy = ({ name, data, formId, id, onBuy, onPay, contractorId, companyId }: IPolicy) => {
  const getDiscountPercentage = (payment, discountedPayment) => {
    return ((payment - discountedPayment) / payment) * 100;
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const min = Math.min(...data.map((d) => d.amount));
  const max = Math.max(...data.map((d) => d.amount));

  const minDiscount = Math.min(...data.map((d) => d.discountedAmount));
  const maxDiscount = Math.max(...data.map((d) => d.discountedAmount));
  
  const policy = useSelector(getSelectedAmountItem);
  const price = policy ? policy.amount : min !== max ? `${min.toFixed(2)} - ${max.toFixed(2)}` : min.toFixed(2);
  const discountedPrice = policy ? policy.discountedAmount : minDiscount !== maxDiscount ? `${minDiscount.toFixed(2)} - ${maxDiscount.toFixed(2)}` : minDiscount.toFixed(2);
  const [maxPercentage, setMaxPercentage] = useState([] as any);
  data.map((d) => setMaxPercentage(getDiscountPercentage(d.amount, d.discountedAmount).toFixed(0)));
  const cashBackPercentage = 10;
  const greenCardCashBack = getCashBack(price, cashBackPercentage);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (onPay) {
      onPay();
    } else if (onBuy) {
      dispatch(setIdPolicy(contractorId))
      onBuy(id);
    }
  };
   
  const img = companyImages.find((company: companyImage) => company.id === companyId)
 
  return (
    <div className="search-result_one">
      <figure className="search-result_pic">
        <img src={img ? require(`../../assets/img/logos/${img.key}`) : "\\img\\base.webp"} alt="" />
      </figure>
      <article className="search-result_info">
        <h4>{name}</h4>
        {min > minDiscount || max > maxDiscount ? 
          <div className="search-result_price">
            <div className="old-price">{price} ₴</div>
            <div>Знижка {Math.max(...maxPercentage)}%</div>
            <div>До сплати {discountedPrice} ₴</div>
          </div> 
          : 
          <div className="search-result_price">{price} ₴ 
            {data.map((item, index) => item.isCashBack && index < 1 ? <div className="cash-back-item">Кешбек на Вашу карту {`${greenCardCashBack.toFixed(2)} ₴ (${cashBackPercentage}%)`}</div> : "")}
          </div>
        }
      </article>
      <div className="search-result_right">
        <button
          form={formId}
          type="submit"
          className="btn btn-link btn-primary btn-buy"
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          {!formId ? "Вибрати" : "Оплатити"}{" "}
          <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Policy;
```

Any ideas how to fix these issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have fixed it by using this code:

```
const maxPercentage = Math.max(...data.map((d) => getDiscountPercentage(d.amount, d.discountedAmount)));

<div>Discount {maxPercentage.toFixed(0)}%</div>
```

Now, it gets the maximum percentage and works well.